# Filling a pandas dataframe with repeating values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, repeat

I have this code in R

```
a <- c(NA)
a<- matrix(c(a), nrow = 80)
a<-as.data.frame(a)

a[ c(T,F,F,F), ] <- "aaa"
a[ c(F,T,F,F), ] <- "bbb"
a[ c(F,F,T,F), ] <- "ccc"
a[ c(F,F,F,T), ] <- "ddd"
```

How can I replicate it in python as a pandas data frame?

```
str(a)
```

> 'data.frame':  80 obs. of  1 variable:
>
> $ V1: chr  "aaa" "bbb" "ccc" "ddd" ...

Comment: What is your expected output? Can you show that?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ should I  add the expected output for his R code? :)

Comment: @Wen Please do buddy!

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ updated :)

Comment: @Wen Cool.... but where are the `aaa` rows??

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ see the `a[ c(T,F,F,F), ] <- "ddd"` I think he overwrite it .

Comment: there was a mistake in the last row, it was overwriting the first one. I have corrected it. I have also shown the output of the "a" dataframe in R

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `np.tile` and construct a series.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

s = pd.Series(np.tile(['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd'], 20) )

print(s.shape) # size - 80 rows
(80,)

print(s.head(10)) # shows only the first 10 rows
0    aaa
1    bbb
2    ccc
3    ddd
4    aaa
5    bbb
6    ccc
7    ddd
8    aaa
9    bbb
dtype: object
```

If you want a dataframe instead, you would do:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'V1' : np.tile(['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd'], 20)})

print(df.head(10))
    V1
0  aaa
1  bbb
2  ccc
3  ddd
4  aaa
5  bbb
6  ccc
7  ddd
8  aaa
9  bbb
```

---

To handle dynamic rows:

```py
vals = ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd', ...]
tiled_vals = np.tile(vals, (80 // len(vals)) + 1 )[:80] # tile and clip to 80

s = pd.Series(tiled_vals)
```

Or,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'V1' : tiled_vals})
```

Comment: The code works static for 80 rows shape, because it multiplies the number of DataFrame elements for the number you write for the function np.tile. What I need is to meet the requirement of 80, because that number happens to be dynamic.

Comment: @anitasp You didn't make that clear. Anyway, the fix is simple, you can check my edit.

Comment: does // is equivalent o R's %%?

Comment: I was running the code for pd.Series and pd.DataFrame. For pd.DataFrame the series are repeated until they meet the parameter 80, for pd.Series it multiplies for that parameter. You gave me the answer there. Thanks.

Comment: @cs95 great tip! using 'total', 'm', 'f' as the tile values to fill, the order was pretty random tho. does np.tile fill alphabetically?

Comment: @Uralan if you tile [a, b, c] N times, the result will always be [a, b, c, a, b, c, a, ...c] (N repetitions).

Answer (score 3):

In Python:

```
['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd']*20
```

In R

```
rep(c('aaa','bbb','ccc','ddd'),20)
```